# Bootstrap selectpicker filters out data attributes (Version 1.13.0-beta)

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-select

I tried for hours today to have Bootstrap selectpicker load with alot of JS (dynamically filling the selectbox).

Now that works, however, when I add attributes (`data-*`) attributes, then I can't access them....

I have a json get in jquery that fills a selectbox:

```
let contact_selector = $('select[name="contact_id"]');
let location_selector = $('select[name="location"]');

$.getJSON({
    url: '{{ url("customers/".$quote->customer->id."/contacts") }}/' + location_selector.val(),
    success: function (data) {
        // fill the contact selector and make sure to refresh the bootstrap selector
        contact_selector.attr('disabled', false);
        contact_selector.children().remove(); // clear the old values
        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
            contact_selector.append($('<option>')
                .text((value.function) ? value.function : '' + ' ' + value.title_relation.nl + ' ' + value.lastname + ' ' + value.firstname)
                .attr('value', value.id))
                .attr('data-contact_titleRelation', value.title_relation.nl)
                .attr('data-contact', value);
        });
        contact_selector.selectpicker('refresh');
        contact_selector.selectpicker('render');
        contact_selector.val('{{ $quote->contact_id }}');
        contact_selector.selectpicker('refresh');
        contact_selector.selectpicker('render');
    }
});
```

This just works, however the `.attr('data-contact_titleRelation', value.title_relation.nl)` and `.attr('data-contact', value)` can't be found when I do the following:

`$('select[name="contact_id"] option:selected').attr('data-contact')`, this throws an undefined error. I've seen in later versions that there is a filter (this version does not have that).

When I want to upgrade to the latest version, all of my selectboxes are broken and nothing works anymore... So I'm looking for a good solution here...

(the double render and refresh is also something stupid, but it doesn't work otherwise...)

Any help?

---

## EDIT

Okey, so the latest version is now working, however, I have done the following:

```
$(function() {
    let defaultWhiteList = $.fn.selectpicker.Constructor.DEFAULTS.whiteList;
    // To allow td elements and data-option attributes  on td elements
    defaultWhiteList.option = ['data-contact', 'data-contact_titleRelation'];
});
```

The filter returns that the option was added. Now the issue is, that I still can't read out the data attributes with the following code: `$('select[name="contact_id"] option:selected').data('contact')`

Comment: The best solution here seems to be to update to the latest version of the library which solves this issue, and then fix whatever bugs you have as a result of the upgrad

Comment: That's the thing, I've tried to implement the latest version, but then selectpickers don't load etc...

Comment: Did you check the console for errors to debug?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to make all the selects selectpickers, anyhow, when I have the latest version implemented, I get another issue, read the edit of the question please :)